# Vt-x is disabled in BIOS - Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Kali Linux 1.0.9

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

I am trying to load Kali Linux(kali-linux-1.0.9a-amd64) on Oracle Virtualbox and encountering the following error.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to enable VT-x within your BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

As already pointed out by Ramhound, the VT-x settings needs to be enabled from the BIOS.

In my case, Intel Virtualization technology had to be **enabled** from:

```
BIOS(Advanced mode) -> CPU configuration -> Intel Virtualization technology
```

Save the settings and restart.